# Create a temporary local html page

Tags: javascript, php

Can someone point me to the right direction, I want to generate an offline webpage in the local browser (memory). Let's say by clicking on a button it open a temporary webpage (from webbrowser) and generate something like

`<html><h1>This is a temporary page, only you can see this</h1></html>`

Edit : This is working but I want to generate it in a new tab or window

```html
<body>
  <script>
    function makeDocument() {
  let frame = document.getElementById("theFrame");

  let doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("New Document");
  let p = doc.createElement("p");
  p.textContent = "This is a new paragraph.";

  try {
    doc.body.appendChild(p);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  // Copy the new HTML document into the frame

  let destDocument = frame.contentDocument;
  let srcNode = doc.documentElement;
  let newNode = destDocument.importNode(srcNode, true);

  destDocument.replaceChild(newNode, destDocument.documentElement);
}
  </script>
  <p>
    Click <a href="javascript:makeDocument()">here</a> to create a new document
    and insert it below.
  </p>
  <iframe id="theFrame" src="about:blank" />
</body>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMImplementation/createHTMLDocument

Comment: @Reyno That's a very good start. Despite opening it on an iframe, is there a way to generate that html page in a new tab ?

Comment: Use `window.open` first, and then work with the contentDocument of that, instead of the frame?

Comment: Can you help me on this?